# How can I prove lim(arctan n)=pi/2 just use definition?

Tags: limits

$$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \arctan { n }  } =\frac { \pi  }{ 2 } $$seems quite obviously, but how can I prove this just using definition of limit?

Answer (score 2):

Note $\arctan(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan (1/x)$ when $x$ is positive.

Then show $$\lim_{x\to 0}\arctan(x)=0.$$